# Is there a way to remove characters that starts with § + 1 character

Tags: python-3.x

python 3.9

```
star = "§c§l2§6§l0§e§l0§a§l*§r"
filter = "§"
    for character in filter:
        star = star.replace(character,"")
        return star
```

how do I make it print out "200*" instead of "§c§l2§6§l0§e§l0§a§l*§r"

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this using `re.sub` as follows:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

star = "§c§l2§6§l0§e§l0§a§l*§r"
output = re.sub(r'§[^§]', '', star)
print(output)  # 200*
```